# How does react re create react element tree (virtual DOM) on every state update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been reading that for every state update react generates the react element tree (virtal dom) and compares the newly generated react element tree( virual dom) with the new one using a diffing algorithm. But here is the confusion.

suppose I have a tree of component
[React component tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcQx8.png)

And if the state is updated in component D, then how does react creates the whole new react element tree (virtual dom) without calling all the components in the tree?

Or does react just creates the virtual element tree for the updated component or what actually happens?

I read a lot of articles about react rendering behavior but couldn't figure out this.

Comment: If state is only set in D, then react will only rerender D (and its children). Does that answer your question, or is there some other detail you're looking for?

Comment: I am actually looking for some details. What I mean to ask if on the first render react creates the react element tree for whole application and when certain component re renders or changes its data then new react element tree is created. My question lies here. If only one component has changed its state in the react element tree then how is it possible to create a new react element tree for the whole application without re executing all the components in the component tree?

Comment: @RanjitBudhathoki please upvot the answer also if it helped you as others can also rely on it

Comment: @Geekyvinayak Sorry ,but stack overflow is not letting me upvote the answer citing it requires minimum 15 reputation to upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a component tree: A -> B -> C -> D
If the state is updated in component D, React will re-render component D.
When component D is re-rendered, React generates a new Virtual DOM representation for D.
React then performs the diffing process between the previous Virtual DOM for D and the new one.
The diffing process identifies the specific changes that occurred in component D's Virtual DOM.
The crucial point to understand is that React's diffing algorithm optimizes the process by focusing only on the components that are affected by the state change. It doesn't trigger rendering for unrelated parts of the component tree.

So, React doesn't re-create the entire Virtual DOM or re-render the entire component tree for every update. It selectively updates only the parts of the Virtual DOM that have changed due to state updates.

This is what makes React efficient and enables it to provide a smooth user experience even in complex applications. The diffing algorithm's ability to identify and apply only the necessary changes reduces unnecessary work and DOM manipulation, resulting in faster and more efficient rendering.

Comment: Ohh okay. So, whenever a state in a component changes then react only re created the virtual dom representation of that respective component and compares that newly generated virtual dom representation with only the respective component previous virtual dom? 

Well this makes sense other wise in order to create complete virtual dom representation on every state update react has to execute all the component again and I don't see any way around.

Answer (score 0):

Process on state update:

Reconciliation and Diffing: React performs a process called reconciliation, where it compares the new Virtual DOM tree with the previous one. It identifies the differences or changes between the old and new trees (diffing).

Minimal Update Calculation: React calculates the minimal set of changes needed to update the actual DOM to reflect the new state. It determines which parts of the Virtual DOM tree have changed.

Updating the Virtual DOM: React updates the existing Virtual DOM tree with the changes identified during the reconciliation process. It doesn't create an entirely new tree but rather updates the existing tree in-memory.

Applying Changes to the Real DOM: React then applies the calculated changes to the real DOM, selectively updating only the specific parts that have changed.

So, to clarify, the new Virtual DOM is essentially the modified version of the previous Virtual DOM, reflecting the changes in state. React optimizes this process by updating only the parts of the Virtual DOM that have changed, rather than recreating the entire tree.

Comment: thank you for your answer but this wasn't my particular question. What I wanted to ask was that when state changes in one of the component , is virtual dom for whole application is recreated or just the part of the updated component?

Comment: @RanjitBudhathoki No problem! I think that were already mentioned, but l will try to clarify:
"Updating the Virtual DOM: React updates the existing Virtual DOM tree with the changes identified during the reconciliation process. It doesn't create an entirely new tree but rather updates the existing tree in-memory."
It means that when app first fully rendered - React construct an entire VDOM.
After that at any update new VDOM constructs like that (merge process):
{...prev VDOM, ...changes in particular component} --> new VDOM.
And, ultimately, VDOM and new VDOM will be compared :)